# Why there is no Hashable interface in Java

Tags: java, interface, hashcode

`Object` in Java has `hashCode` method, however, it is being used only in associative containers like `HashSet` or `HashMap`. Why was it designed like that? `Hashable` interface having `hashCode` method looks as much more elegant solution.

Comment: Why do you need special interface when you can override it every where and Object is by default super class of all?

Comment: @Namban The question is more of "Why does every Object have a hashCode() method, when it's only used by a few java.util.* collection classes." i.e. why isn't there e.g. an ObjectHash interface, just as there's a Comparable interface, etc.

Comment: This is more of a discussion topic than a question, so it's not really suitable for SO.

Comment: @nos: After comments, I see little bit sense in the question, still my argument is, hashcode is not just used in collection interface/implementations, you may use for equality irrespective of where the object is being used.

Comment: Why should there be a separate interface??  Every object needs those two methods (they're used by stuff other than HashMap, et al), so they properly "belong" to Object.  Adding a Hashable interface would just be unnecessary clutter.

Comment: @HotLicks where is `hashCode` used other than in hash-based collections?

Comment: @GiovanniBotta - The point is that every Object (or subclass of Object) must implement `hashCode`, so there's no point in breaking it out as a separate interface.  It would just be additional "noise".

Comment: @HotLicks why? What if I never use a hash-based collection? For example, why does `Thread` need a `hashCode` and an `equals` method?

Comment: @GiovanniBotta - Because the Hashtable and HashMap classes accept *any* object.

Comment: @HotLicks except they shouldn't. This is true in many other languages, e.g., in C++ default hash functions are implicitly defined only for types where it makes sense (built in types, strings, pairs of those).

Comment: @HotLicks note that java suffers from legacy design problems. In the absence of generics, it would have been really difficult if not impossible to define hash-based collections without assuming that every object type provides its own `hashCode` and `equals` methods. Sorted collections do require that the user specifies the object's `Comparator` or that the object implements `Comparable`: do you think the `compareTo` method should be moved into the `Object` class? I don't think the Java language team believes in that.

Comment: @HotLicks Sorry for the rant, but one more point I wanted to make: as with sorted collections, in some instances it might make sense to provide a specific hash function for a specific usage of a collection, just like you can specify any arbitrary `Comparator` to modify the ordering of the collection. This might be an advanced use case but the language doesn't really support it right now.

Comment: How do you decide which classes "make sense" for membership in a hash-based collection?  Just because the developer of the class foresees no need for it doesn't mean that some user of the class might no want the hash function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The major argument seems to me that there is a well-defined default `hashCode` that can be calculated for any Java object, along with an equally well-defined `equals`. There is simply no good reason to withhold this function from all objects, and of course there are plenty reasons **not** to withhold it. So it's a no-brainer in my book.

Comment: I don't think he's stating there should be a general procedure for obtaining `hashCode`; he's stating that `hashCode` should be made a part of some interface `Hashable` and not left in `Object`.

Comment: @veer OK, now I see. I misread. But still, it's just a slightly different reason then.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik no, that's clearly not what he's stating. `Hashtable` wouldn't need to compute the `hashCode` of any object; the difference is that only `Object`s which need a `hashCode` would implement `Hashable`. Think of it like this, `HashMap<K extends Hashable, V>` vs `HashMap<K, V>`

Comment: @veer, I've updated the comment and the answer already. I misread `Hashable` for `Hashtable`. Everything is clear now.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I responded while you were editing your response :-)

Comment: My answer to the question would be that there is an implementation that all `Object`s have that not all users could reimplement for themselves -- namely the sort-of-memory-address-based implementation currently provided by `Object.hashCode()`.

Comment: @LouisWasserman An instance method of Object is not the only way they could get that, though, but still a very good point.

Comment: IMO the absence of a `Hashable` interface and even better of a super-interface of `Hashable` for one-way comparisons, i.e., that defines the equals method, is one of the biggest shortcomings of the language. The default implementation of `hashCode` and `equals` are so rarely useful that I would rather require these methods to be explicitly defined by the user so that the user is forced to understand their meaning and implications. I found that understanding the need to override these two methods is one of the biggest humps in the learning curve for the language.

Comment: @GiovanniBotta: IMHO, there are *two* equivalence relations any object should be able to answer with regard to any object reference: (1) Will it always be equivalent to the object identified by the reference, no matter what is done to those objects or anything else; (2) Will it be equivalent to the object identified by the reference if nothing is done to it which would change its equivalence class?  Some types define equivalence one way; some define it the other.  IMHO, Java would be much better if there were standard ways to query the two relationships separately, and if...

Comment: ...collections had constructor parameters to specify how the equivalence of their contents should relate to their own equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

This question is claimed as a duplicate from another which asks why there's no interface which behaves like `Comparator` (as distinct from `Comparable`) but for hashing.  .NET includes such an interface, called `IEqualityComparer`, and it would seem like Java could as well.  As it is, if someone wants to e.g. have a Java collection which e.g. maps strings to other objects in case-insensitive fashion (perhaps the most common use of `IEqualityComparer`) one must wrap the strings in objects whose `hashCode` and `equals` methods act on a case-insensitive basis.

I suspect the big issue is that while an "equalityComparer" interface could be convenient, in many cases efficiently testing an equivalence relation would require caching information.  For example, while a case-insensitive string-hashing function could make an uppercase-only copy of the passed-in string and call `hashCode` on that, it would be difficult to avoid having every request for the hashcode of a particular string repeat the conversion to uppercase and the hashing of that uppercase value.  By contrast, a "case-insensitive string" object could include fields for an uppercase-only copy of the string, which would then only have to be generated once for the instance.

An `EqualityComparer` could achieve reasonable performance if it included something like a `WeakHashMap<string,string>` to convert raw strings to uppercase-only strings, but such a design would either require different threads to use different `EqualityComparer` instances despite the lack of externally visible state, or else require performance-robbing locking and synchronization code even in single-threaded scenarios.

Incidentally, a second issue that arises with comparator-style interfaces is that a collection type which uses an externally-supplied comparator (whether it compares for rank or equality) is that the comparator itself becomes part of the state of the class which uses it.  If hash tables use different EqualityComparer instances, there may be no way to know that they can safely be considered equivalent, even if the two comparators would behave identically in all circumstances.