# Why doesn't Java have an interface similar to Comparator, but for hashing?

Tags: java, collections, hash, comparator

In Java, the Comparator interface allows a client to specify an equals() and compare() method for any type. A Comparator can be passed to most (or maybe all) collections that require sorting, and the methods in the Comparator will be used instead of the methods of the specified class. This allows clients to sort objects in a way that is different from their natural ordering, or even to sort objects that don't have a natural ordering (i.e. don't implement Comparable).

Why isn't there a similar interface for hashing? It could specify two methods, hashCode() and equals(), and be useful for HashSets or HashMaps in the same way Comparators are useful for sorting.

Edit: For those who marked this question a duplicate of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12132880/why-there-is-no-hashable-interface-in-java), I would mention that the other question asks why hashCode is included in every class instead of an interface, while this question is about abstracting the hashing function to allow multiple implementations of it.

Answer Edit: The best methods of getting this functionality seem to be:

-If you're ok using an external library and/or are already using Guava (which is a fantastic library for a lot of reasons), Guava has an [Equivalence](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) class that allows this.

-If you don't want to use an external library, you can use a custom built adapter, similar to what is done in the top answer on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094818/compare-two-java-collections-using-comparator-instead-of-equals).

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094818/compare-two-java-collections-using-comparator-instead-of-equals

Comment: `equals()` and `hashCode()` are defined in the `Object` class, so **every** class already has them

Comment: Firstly, `hashCode` is native implementation from `Object`. That means that it will always be defined in any class. `equals` is also defined in Object. Both of those would always be defined in any instance, so having an interface for them would make no sense.

Comment: @Legend. Of course it could make sense. In a particular context, you could want to consider persons equal if the have the same name, whereas in another, you could want to consider them equal if they have the same SSN. Just like you do with a Comparator, you could externalize that to an "Equalizer". The adapter pattern is probably the best solution to solve this problem (admittedly lmuch less frequent than wanting to sort objects in different ways)

Comment: See Guava's [Equivalence](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html)

Comment: @JBNizet no reason that has to be handled outside the equals method.

Comment: @Legend An equals method can't have two different implementations.

Comment: @JBNizet what makes yours any different? If Sun saw this was needed it would be added. This would be a waste of time, space and practice. Make your own if you are so heartbent on having it.

Comment: You say that it makes no sense. That's plain wrong. It makes sense. Guava has created such a thing. It also has Multimap for example. Are you saying that a Multimap doesn't make sense, just because Sun has not added it in the JDK? Jus because it isn't useful to *you* doesn't mean it makes no sense.

Comment: If it was needed it would have been added. /discussion

Comment: Even good ideas are not free to add.  It not being added does not mean it is not a good idea.

Comment: OK. So I guess you never use any external library in any of your programs, right. You're being more and more ridiculous. They probably chose not to do it because it's nod needed often enough. That doesn't mean it's never needed.

Comment: Actually, it means never writing new code. If it was needed, it would have already been written!

Comment: @sharakan thanks for the link; I agree that the adapter pattern seems like the best solution without using an external library. It's a little unfortunate something more elegant isn't a part of Java.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks for the link to Equivalence. I wondered if there might be something in Guava before I posted the questions, but I only poked around a little in the collect package, I didn't think it would be in base.

Comment: I don't consider this question a duplicate of the cited one, since it's asking about an equivalent of `Comparator` rather than `Comparable`.  A `Hashable` interface would be needless, since all objects already implement it, but an equivalent to .NET's `IEquatable` would be helpful, though not without problems which could be described at greater length in a proper answer.  I think the biggest issue is that while it may be useful to have e.g. a case-insensitive string comparer, there would be no clean way for such a thing to cache hashcodes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions of the form

> "Why doesn't Java have XXX"

are difficult to answer objectively except with a generic

> "We don't know because nobody here was in the room when the decision was made."

In this case:

- On the face of it, this requirement can be implemented ... from a technical perspective.
- This requirement has been proposed numerous times via RFEs.  The most direct one is  https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6435963.  The RFE is marked as WONT FIX, though no particular reason is given.
- This requirement could be, and has been adequately met by 3rd party libraries.

*My reading* of this is that it is not supported because it has not been deemed important enough for enough people that it needs to be supported.  I'd say they made a reasonable call on that.

Comment: I agree with everything in your answer from the analysis of the question to your reading. I was mostly wondering if there was a reason besides the fact that it wouldn't be useful in many cases. Also thanks for the link to the relevant RFE.

Comment: *"I was mostly wondering if there was a reason besides the fact that it wouldn't be useful in many cases."* - It is simply an observed fact.  In the vast majority of cases, a key object's "natural" equals and hashcode is fine.  Why?  Maybe because people don't use "funky keys"?   Or because if the do use "funky keys" then they use TreeMaps rather than HashMaps?

Comment: In the good old days you could get a rough measure of how much support an RFE had based on the number of votes it had in the Bug Parade.  Unfortunately, Oracle decided they didn't want to know anymore.

Comment: For many questions of the form "why doesn't X do Y", there is an analogous question "If someone were designing something similar to X, would having it do Y be less useful or more problematic than it would at first glance appear"?  People need not have had any involvement in the implementation of X to answer the latter question; in many cases, finding out non-obvious reasons why something *shouldn't* be done may be extremely useful, but in many cases it's not possible to know whether a question will have a useful answer without knowing what the answer is.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that such an interface would be handy, specifically as a way to consider different kinds of equalities in collections.  It should be similar to the way that you can make an object `Comparable`, but still override that behavior in a specific collection by providing some other `Comparator`.

As was pointed out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15094818/compare-two-java-collections-using-comparator-instead-of-equals), Guava has an [`Equivalence`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Equivalence.html) class that provides a way to do this, by wrapping your class and letting you define at the wrapper level what 'equality' means in this context.

If your question is really why this didn't happen at language design time...  well, hey, [James Gosling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Gosling) and company are only human, right?

Answer (score 0):

Hashing has really just one requirement: Being like a hash method. So you can implement it for a type without knowing who will use it in what way and for what purpose. So the hash method on the object itself is sufficient.

Equals on the other hand has different meanings in different contexts. For example you can sort people by first name, last name, age, size, weight, time of membership in a club ... So it makes sense to have different implementations of equal (and 'less than') for a single class.

Of course nothing keeps you from creating such an interface and using it ...

Comment: The `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods are inexorably linked.  If a type has multiple sensible meanings for `equals()`, it will generally have just as many sensible meanings for `hashCode()`.  It may be possible to construct a `hashCode()` implementation that will work acceptably for multiple `equals` methods [e.g. both case-sensitive and case-insensitive compares could use a hash value computed from an uppercase-only version of a string], but such methods will generally not be optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the hashcode() to say how the HashMap arranges your object in Map and improve its performence by implementing an effective hashcode method in your class.

How HashMap performs addition and removal from a hashed data is internal to HashMap and changing it would basically mean changing add,remove methods etc.

Also sorting is a common feature that is used more often and for a rare case when you really want to change how hashing happens in a map then there is always the option to extend a Map.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to say how I see it, why.

Briefly - you often need to **sort** a list **objects**, but you rare (if ever) need to cross compare **identities** of a list of **object**.

---

In Object, method **hashCode** is a secondary, helpful method, which main purpose is to serve the **equals** method. The agreement is that if for two objects **hashCode** returns different values, **equals** mustn't return true.

So, methods **hashCode** and **equals** serve to establish the **identity** of an object.

Method **compareTo** (in both Comparable and Comparator) serves another general purpose. It defines **objects order**, not their **identity**.

Resume - **compareTo** defines how the **objects** are **ordered**, **hashCode** (together with **equals**) defines **objects identity**.

---

Again - practice contribution is that you often have to sort a group of **objects**, but you rare (if ever) have to take a group of **objects** and cross compare their **identities**.